# Changing the number of columns dynamically in SQL MS Access 2007

Tags: sql, ms-access, vba, ms-access-2007, dynamic-sql

I am SQL beginner and woriking on MS Access 2007 I am trying to add multiple columns together but the number of columns to be included in query are going to change always. For example I have to calculate the Year to date budget, every time user will execute the query, a new date will be entered and I have Month1, Month2, Month3...Month 12 columns. I am confused on how can I decide on run time that how many columns I am going to include in the query. 
If user enters 8/31/2017 I have to pick Month1, Month2, Month3, Month4, Month5 (They are Fiscal year-months)

[image].

Comment: Why are you storing data in wide format? Store value data in long format with only **one** Month column and indicators for fiscal year and months. Your queries will be much easier. Long formats are better in storing/retrieval efficiency, maintainability, and scalability.

Comment: I agree with the above comment - with the data stored in long format, you can write a crosstab query that will allow it to be displayed with variable columns, as per your question.

Comment: @Parfait I have no control over table of the data , I am getting views that I have to work on

Comment: If you receive data in this format, they are intended for spreadsheet use. But Access is not a spreadsheet, so normalise the data as @Parfait suggests as the first step, then use these data for the further processing.

Answer (score 0):

That's a horrible idea!!  Store your dates like this.

[image]

QryYTD:
Code:

```
SELECT
    Sum(qryNet.Net) AS YTD
FROM
   qryNet
WHERE
   (((qryNet.OrderDate) Between DateSerial(Year(Date()),1,1) AND   Date()))
```

QryMTD:
Code:

```
SELECT
    Sum(qryNet.Net) AS MTD
FROM
   qryNet
WHERE
   (((qryNet.OrderDate) Between DateSerial(Year(Date()),Month(Date()),1) 
AND
   Date()));
```

QryWTD:
Code:

```
SELECT
    Sum(qryNet.Net) AS WTD
FROM
   qryNet
WHERE
   (((qryNet.OrderDate) Between DateAdd("d",-Weekday(Date()),Date()+2) 
AND
   Date()));
```

As written, qryWTD uses the current Monday as the starting date.

Once you have the three working, you could create a wrapper query by adding each of the previous queries and specifying YTD, MTD and WTD as the query's fields.